# Div Content Not Appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that under certain circumstance some items show a little red box (think facebook friend count).

I've recently redone the css targetting the menu but nothing should have changed to cause the problem I'm seeing.

It's a simple div like this:

```
<div id="request-count" class="noticount"></div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
.noticount {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E43C03;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've  checked the page sounce and my javascript is correctly setting the value so the div ends up looking like this:

```
<div id="request-count" class="noticount">1</div>
```

The only way I can get this to actually show up is by manually hacking the live CSS and setting the Width and Height, then it shows up without a problem.

The **really** odd bit is that the content "1" never shows in the div either.  Very confused over this and really don't know what to try.

Not sure if this is significant or an oddity with FireBug but sometimes this div appears in the code view slightly tranparanent which usually disnifies that an element is `display:none` which I'm not getting either.

What can I try to solve this?

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle displaying the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/UYa5Z/

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: so when you inspect it, the 1 is, or isn't appearing in the div?

Comment: Where is your jQuery?

Comment: works here:http://jsfiddle.net/NRZ3J/

Comment: `.noticount` is absolutely positioned, so it will be to the top left of the browser window unless it is within some ancestor containing block that is not statically positioned.  We really need so see a bit more HTML/CSS to appreciate the problem.

Comment: It's hard to debug this without a working example. In debugging these types of things, I find it useful to give the element an obvious background color (temporarily) and remove any positioning first.

Comment: I've added a fiddle showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact reason, but it appears that the formatting of your font-size is not working as intended.  With the example that you linked, if you simply change the `font-size` of the `noticount` class from `em` based to `px` based it seems to fix the issue.

```
.noticount {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E43C03;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10px; /* this instead of font-size: 0.6em */
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uLXR/)

**Edit:**

Based on my second comment below, I investigated the issue further.  As [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BG8KW/) shows, you can keep `.noticount`'s `font-size` relative if you remove the `font-size: 0;` from both `ul#moomenu` and `ul#moomenu li`.  I'm not sure what the purpose of setting those to `0`, but given you use `px` (instead of `em`) on `ul#moomenu a` and `ul#moomenu ul a` I'd suggest using my first suggested fix as it's consistent with the other font-sizes you set in your css.

Comment: Nice one!  That has only really added to the confusion but does indeed fix the issue.

Comment: @Jammer, I totally agree... I'll let you know if I can find any research or figure out why this issue exists.

Comment: Gotta be some crazy odd interaction thing going on.

Comment: did you try using `rem` instead of `em`?

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk, not before no.  But going back to the original JSFiddle by @Jammer, it also fixes the problem.  Based on [this](http://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/) article, it leads me to believe that Niet the Dark Absol, was on the right path to finding the root of this issue (60% of 0 is 0).  Given that, somewhere you're setting some parent of the div to `0` (intentionally or otherwise).  If you want to keep the font size relative, I'd suggest revisiting all of where you set font size in your CSS (and possibly your JS) file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent of`.noticount`has a `relative`position that will fixe the problem

```
.noticountParent{
     position:relative;
}

.noticount{
     position:absolute;
}
```

Html:

```
<article class=noticountParent>
    <div id="request-count" class="noticount">1</div>
</article>
```

Comment: The parent is already relative positioned, that's what's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul#moomenu` and `ul#moomenu li` define `font-size:0`

Since the `.noticount` has `font-size:0.6em`, the resulting font size is... `0`

A font size of zero is invisible.

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle (or similar service) example working with this change?  I took out the `font-size:0` you're referencing and still see the OP's described issue.

Comment: @user3507600 There's apparently another place. Hold on.

Comment: [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/UYa5Z/3/), but note that since list items don't have the proper `position:relative`, the notification appears in the wrong place.